# Pre-Calculus Complex Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[image]

My younger cousin asked for help on his math homework and I don't remember doing this, can anyone help please? The denominator of $w$ has $z^*+1$ where the $^*$ means to negate the $z$ term so $z^*= -a-bi$.

Comment: You better write the expression using MathJax instead of using a blurry pic.

Comment: By "my younger cousin" I suppose that you mean yourself. Regardless, the complex conjugate of $z=a+ib$ is defined as $\bar{z}=a-ib$, not $-a-ib$.

Comment: Probably $z^\ast$ is intended to be the conjugate of $z$. Then I would make the denominator real by multiplying top and bottom by $z+1$.

Comment: @Gahawar There's no reason to accuse the poster of lying about who this is for; it's aggressive and entirely irrelevant to the point - an answer never needs to know who's asking, it just needs the question (and this question isn't really too bad; it shows enough effort to aid answerers, even if that effort needs to be squinted at a lot to make sense of it - I'd rather not try scaring off new users for such a trivial thing).

Comment: Note that the "*" means to negate the imaginary part of the expression that carries it, not the entire expression. So, for example $(2+3i)^*=2-3i$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it looks like the approach is right, but the calculations go bad. Of course, this could be just be because the picture is hard to read. Anyways, things start pretty well - I see the fraction
$$w=\frac{a+bi+1}{a-bi+1}$$
Then, it looks like they try to get rid of the imaginary component of the denominator by multiplying the numerator and denominator by *something*. I'm not sure exactly what goes wrong here in their calculation, but the denominator in the next step doesn't look like it should. If you want to get rid of the complex denominator, you want to multiply by the conjugate (i.e. that start operator $(a+bi)^*=a-bi$) of the denominator, since the product of a number by its conjugate is always real. So, the conjugate of the denominator is $a+bi+1$, and when you multiply that out you get (notice that I grouped the real component $(a+1)$ into one term for ease):
$$w=\frac{(a+1)^2 + 2(a+1)bi - b^2 }{(a+1)^2 + b^2}$$
From which point, you can group the coefficients of $i$ and of $1$ (since the denominator is real) to get
$$w=\left(\frac{(a+1)^2-b^2}{(a+1)^2+b^2}\right)+\left(\frac{2(a+1)b}{(a+1)^2+b^2}\right)\cdot i$$
which is the desired form.

Notice that this could easily follow from expanding the fraction
$$\frac{k}{k^*}$$
for a complex $k$ and then setting $k=z+1$, since $(z+1)^*=z^*+1$. (Of course, in this case, you still have to do the same ordeal, but it's maybe a bit more clean)

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}
w & =\frac{z+1}{z^\ast+1}
\\ & = \frac{a+1+b\mathrm i}{a+1-b\mathrm i}
\\ & = \frac{a+1+b\mathrm i}{a+1-b\mathrm i}\cdot\frac{a+1+b\mathrm i}{a+1+b\mathrm i}
\\ & = \frac{(a+1)^2-b^2 + 2(a+1)b\mathrm i}{(a+1)^2+b^2}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

$w=\frac{z+1}{z^*+1}=\frac{a+bi+1}{a-bi+1}=\frac{a+1+bi}{a+1-bi}=\frac{a+1+bi}{a+1-bi}\frac{a+1+bi}{a+1+bi}=\frac{(a+1)^2+2(a+1)bi-b^2}{(a+1)^2+b^2}=\frac{(a+1)^2-b^2}{(a+1)^2+b^2}+\frac{2(a+1)b}{(a+1)^2+b^2}i$

The final expression on the right is in $x+yi$ form. For $w$ to be real, the imaginary part, $y$, needs to be $0$. That means $\frac{2(a+1)b}{(a+1)^2+b^2}=0$, or more simply $2(a+1)b=0$. This will only be true when $a=-1$ or $b=0$. In more explicit terms, this will be when $z$ is real, or when $z=-1+bi$

Answer (score 0):

I'll mention that you can also go a little more directly by multiplying the numerator and denominator of $ \ w \ $ by $ \ z \ + \ 1 \ $ , giving

$$ w \ \ = \ \ \frac{z \ + \ 1}{z^* \ + \ 1} \ \cdot \ \frac{z \ + \ 1}{z \ + \ 1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{(z \ + \ 1)^2}{zz^* \ + \ (z \ + \ z^*) \ + \ 1} \ \ . $$

We can now use the facts that $ \ zz^* \ = \ a^2 \ + \ b^2 \ $ and that $ \ z \ + \ z^* \ = \ 2a \ $ .  Along with writing $ \ z \ + \ 1 \ $ as $ \ (a + 1) \ + \ bi \ $ , we then have

$$ w \ \ = \ \  \frac{( \ [a + 1] \ + \ bi \ )^2}{a^2 \ + \ b^2  \ + \ 2a \ + \ 1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{( \ [a + 1]^2 \ - \ b^2 \ ) \ + \ 2 \ (a+1) \ bi \ }{(a \ + \ 1)^2 \ + \  b^2  } \ \ . $$